# Java: How to parse a String?

Tags: java

How to get last path `path_X`?

```
/some/random/path_1/
/some/random/path_2
```

Thus, it is necessary to use 3rd party libraries like `Guava` or `Apache Commons`.

Comment: What do you exactly want? I think it's not very clear your question.

Comment: Is it always /xxx/xxx/path_X?

Comment: `new File("/x/y/z/").getName()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
final String last = Paths.get("/some/random/path_1/").getFileName().toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this would also work, yes?

```
String fileName = new File(path).getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be

```
String s = "/some/random/path_1/";
String[] sa = s.split("/");

String last = sa[sa.length-1]);
```